# How to change the field label on my registration form? Drupal 7

Tags: users, forms

On the default registration form, I want to change the Username label to 'Request your username'

I tried putting this in my template.php::

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
        $form['account']['name']['#title'] = t('Request your username');
    }
}
```

I cleared cache, but didn't see any changes.

Comment: template.php is a theme file, not a module file - therefore it should read mytheme_form_alter(...), or you need to create a custom module so that it becomes theme independant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested on a D7 site and it should work fine for you if you name the alter function "mytheme_form_alter" instead of "mymodule_form_alter"?

See this answer for more detail on module options: [Changing the registration form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2747/changing-the-registration-form)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can alter it using form_alter() like suggested in this post [User Login Form alters](https://www.drupal.org/node/19855)
2. Otherwise there is [String Overrides Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) which is used to alter simple labels... here is a [Tutorial](http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/10/27/how-replace-texts-string-overrides-module-drupal-7) for it.. !!!