# Overriding field label

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to override the label of the picture field.  I've started with the code here:

[How to change the field label on my registration form? Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135539/how-to-change-the-field-label-on-my-registration-form-drupal-7)

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
  dsm($form_id);
    $form['account']['picture']['#title'] = t('Profile Picture');
}
}
```

[image]

I just want to override the "PICTURE" title to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual code should be:

I have used [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) instead of hook_form_alter().

```
function test_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Used dpm() to check for picture array.
  $form['picture']['#title'] = t('Profile Picture');
}
```

Result:
[image]

**Note:** The capitalization of all the character must be coming from theming layer.

Use [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) for development:
The structure has changed and the account array no longer holds picture array.

[image]